# Space around the image in a table issue

Tags: html

I am facing an issue with the white space around the image in table.

My code :

```
<table style="font-size: 18px; width: 60%; color: #ffffff;  margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; cellspacing=0px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:22px; height:22px;"><img src="img/top_left_corner.png"/></td>
                            <td style="background-color:#00385e;"></td>
                            <td><img src="img/top_right_corner.png"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color:#00385e;"></td>
                            <td style="background-color:#00385e;">
                                Please join us on Thursday 15th May to celebrate Global Accessibility Awareness Day and to find out more about the importance of web accessibility.</br></br>
                                <b>Location: </b> Manyata Tech Park - G2 4th Floor - Board Room</br>
                                <b>Date: </b> 15th May 2014 (Thursday)</br>
                                <b>Time: </b> 3pm to 4pm</br>
                            </td>
                            <td style="background-color:#00385e;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="img/bottom_left_corner.png"/></td>
                            <td style="background-color:#00385e;"></td>
                            <td><img src="img/bottom_right_corner.png"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

The table is looking like:

---

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. what are you using this old style for round corners while you can simply do this with css border radius? And your content is more appropriate to use a div other than table. 2. if you do have to use this method, apply padding:0 to your td element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `padding:0` to all tds

```
table td{
  padding:0;
}
```

Hope this will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css:

```
img{
   display:block;
}
```